# Appium with WinAppDriver: How to Skip Over Certain Nodes During XPath Search

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, appium, winappdriver

Short Version: How do I get my XPath search to ignore certain nodes, and not waste time checking them or their children?

Full Version: I'm automating a Windows Desktop Application using Appium and WinAppDriver, and I need my XPath search to skip over certain child nodes which are slowing things down.

The Application Under Test (AUT) is 30 years of bad practices built on terrible foundation, and it's got some hiccups. Here are the things that (I'm pretty sure) are non-negotiable:

1. The Windows Driver has to point to Root, because nearly every action performed on the AUT will open a new window as a child of Root, not of the original application window. I suppose I could spin up a new driver every time the AUT creates a new window, but that's been inconsistent so far, and just feels like an inefficient solution. Switching windows also doesn't work, because the Window Handle changes every time the application launches.
2. The driver has to find most elements by Dynamic XPath, because no one thought to give anything a unique ID or Class Name, and many elements don't even have a Name. So accessing those elements often requires some extra spicy navigation. (Example: `//Window[@Name='Signature Validation']//Pane[contains(@Name, 'EXAM')]//List/child::*[contains(@Name, 'date')]`)

---

My Xpath searches had been inconsistently timing out or failing, and I finally tracked it down to open applications which have a ton of child elements (Outlook, Microsoft Teams, any web browser, etc). If I close everything other than my IDE and the AUT before running tests, they run just fine. But when it has to scan through every child element of my Outlook Inbox it will throw NoSuchElementException about 80% of the time.

I've been trying to write an XPath query which will automatically skip the Outlook window and all of its children. I tried a couple variations on this sort of thing:

```
//Window[not(self::Window[@Name='Foo']) and [@Name='Bar']]
//Window[not(self::Window[@Name='Foo'] or ancestor::Window[@Name='Foo']) and [@Name='Bar']]
/*[not(self::*[contains(@Name, 'Foo')]) and self::Window[contains(@Name, 'Bar')]]
```

But it seems like it's still scanning Outlook and its children, because I'm still seeing

```
Exception: Encountered element sharing the same runtimeId
...
Ignoring new object and keeping existing one
```

tens of times before it throws NoSuchElementException on a query that runs successfully when Outlook is closed. That suggests to me that it's still combing through Outlook on its way down the DOM.

Since my driver has to have access to Root and all of its child elements, is there a way to mark Outlook and certain other child nodes as strictly *verboten*, and get my XPath search to skip over them entirely?

---

Right now this is a one-person team, so it's not a hassle to close out applications that I know are going to cause issues prior to execution. But eventually we're going to expand the team and I want things to be smooth and intuitive (as much as possible given the circumstances) when they get here.

Note: I've looked through similar questions and I don't think any of them are asking the same thing that I am. I know how to exclude nodes from the **results** of an XPath search, but I'm trying to remove those nodes from the search entirely. Thank you so much if you're able to offer any suggestions!